# Multi Domain Robots.txt

Tags: multi-sites

I have multiple sites running on a single code base in Drupal 8. Is there any possible way to add different robots.txt file for each site?

Comment: `I have multiple sites running on a single code` care to mention how you managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are under apache, you can use mod_rewrite to deliver others robots.txt :

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
  RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots.domain1.com.txt [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$
  RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots.domain2.com.txt [L]
```

Note you may also generate your robots.txt in some controller for each site depends on config and fallback to default if not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The [RobotsTXT module](https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt) lets you have a different robots.txt for each site in a multisite setup. It also gives you the chance to edit via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have 2 modules:

- [RobotsTxt](https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt)
- [Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) (here we have included Domain Configuration UI module)

2. Enable RobotsTxt and Domain Configuration UI modules.
3. On the RobotsTxt configuration form (https://[your_website]/admin/config/search/robotstxt) you should see a "Enable domain configuration" button. Just click on the button.
4. After, you will see a "Domain Configuration" container at the top of the RobotsTxt configuration page where you can switch between domains and apply related configuration.